# how to expose apache docker container on port 8080 rather than port 80

Tags: docker, port, port-forwarding, docker-compose, docker-networking

I have a webserver running on port 80 , however I need the site to be accessed using 172.16.21.2:8080 , regardless of what port mapping i specify it is always accessed using port 80. How can i make my containers be accessed than a different port than 80.

```
version: '3'
services:
  apache:
    image: httpd:latest
    networks:
      LAN:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.21.2
    ports:
      - "8080:80"   
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
networks:
  LAN:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `- "8080:80"` specifies that port 80 on the container shall be mapped to port 80 on the post. Change the `80` to whatever port you want, e.g. port 8080. based on your question.